# Jackson Json With assign to Different type (deserializing and sererializing)

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

How can change the return byte to bitmap in json processing?

```
private Bitmap imageBitmap;
private byte[] image;

@JsonProperty("image")
public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}  

public Bitmap getImageBitmap() {
    return imageBitmap;
}
@JsonProperty("image")
public void setImageBitmap(byte[] imageBitmap) {
    this.imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JsonIngore` for unused getters and setters.

```
private Bitmap imageBitmap;
private byte[] image;

@JsonProperty("image")
public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}  

@JsonIgnore
public Bitmap getImageBitmap() {
    return imageBitmap;
}
@JsonProperty("image")
public void setImageBitmap(byte[] imageBitmap) {
    this.imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBitmap);
}
```

Comment: i have null json even if i have @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

Comment: Can you provide more code or more detail in which case you have null json.

Comment: the return of @JsonProperty("image") from server is a byte.. i like to dont use  the byte property because i only need bitmap for the android application.. thanks for the help